# Как загрузить в ObjectManager несколько файлов Json?

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api

Имеется несколько файлов с геоданными вида Json. Загружаю их при помощи следующего кода в js:

```
$.getJSON('data_obj.json')
    .done(function (geoJson) {
        objectManager.add(geoJson);
    });
$.getJSON('data.json')
    .done(function (geoJson) {
        objectManager.add(geoJson);
    });
$.getJSON('data_osv.json')
    .done(function (geoJson) {
        objectManager.add(geoJson);

        map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    });
```

Объекты на карте отображаются, но не все. Как правильно в js прописать ассинхронную загрузку геоданных, чтобы все объекты выводились на карте?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не такой уж и дубликат. там речь о том, чтобы в принципе получить результат из асинхронной функции. Здесь вопрос о том, чтобы синхронизовать результат трех функций

Comment: Может немного не так объяснил суть вопроса. По факту грузятся все три базы, однако одна из них не загружается вся. Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждая новая база загружалась после полной загрузки предыдущей.

Comment: @teran там описываются принцип работы с асинхронными функциями. Если будет понимание, что это такое, то применить те подходы можно будет и здесь.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы на карту надо добавить результат трех вызовов, то и добавляйте их после третьего. То есть подсчитайте, что все три завершились.

```
let cc = 0;
function updateMap(geoJson){
    objectManager.add(geoJson);
    if(++cc == 3){
        map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    }
}

$.getJSON('data_obj.json', updateMap);
$.getJSON('data.json',     updateMap);
$.getJSON('data_osv.json', updateMap);
```

Comment: Спасибо всем. Ошибка оказывается была в одинаковых ID в разных файлах баз, и именно из-за этого файлы частично не загружались. Код приведенный здесь работает, буду использовать его.